# ModelImporter.globalScale AssetPostprocessor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since isFileScaleUsed is Read-only, this script detects the File Scale and Recalculates the Scale Factor( Global Scale) accordingly.

```
using UnityEditor;


public class FBXScaleFix : AssetPostprocessor
{
  public void OnPreprocessModel()
  {
  ModelImporter modelImporter = (ModelImporter)assetImporter;
  modelImporter.globalScale = 1.0f / modelImporter.fileScale;
  UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Import file scale: " + modelImporter.fileScale + ", global scale: " + modelImporter.globalScale);

  }
}
```

Problem is that `OnPreprocessModel` fileScale is detected as 1 but it shows after 0.01 ( example number )

But if you change any setting inside inspector the object Scale Factor( Global Scale) scales to normal value, in this example 100

This doesn't work either

```
public void OnPostprocessModel()
{
   ModelImporter modelImporter = (ModelImporter)assetImporter;
   importer.importMaterials = false;
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: If you just set modelImporter.globalScale = 100f, does it give the same behavior? Are you on the latest version of Unity?

Comment: yes but not every model imported has the same scale. I want to have all models at standard scale. And yes latest version

Comment: This sounds like a bug.